# Method to replace fragments as quickly as possible

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to know if there is a method to replace fragments one after other as soon as the previous fragment becomes visible. Basically I need to take screenshots of 8 fragments by loading them one by one.

Load Frag1-> take screenshot(when view is ready)-> (after screenshot)replace Frag1 with Frag2-> take screenshot(when view is ready)-> (after screenshot)replace Frag2 with Frag3-> take screenshot(when view is ready)-> .... so on

I tried replacing fragments one after other but I am getting null instances for all the previous 7 and the last loaded 8th fragment is active so I can take screenshot of last fragment alone.

Please provide a solution or a design idea to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can load all the fragment into a ViewPager and auto scroll the pager once the screenshot is finished.

Comment: I can do that but in view of performance issues I have a requirement that I shouldn't load all fragments initially. As you know viewpager loads only 2 at a time, I have to abide by this. Can you let me know of any other method.

Comment: You can use mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(x); where x = the number of pages you want to load off screen.

Comment: I tried this method but with respect to performance this is not advisable.